# Is it permissable to be in a musical group that does not exclusively play simchas?

Tags: halacha, music, performance-entertainment

Is it permissible to play in a musical group that does not only play at 'simchas' (weddings, etc.)? I once heard someone say that playing any music in public that is not for a specific mitzvah is forbidden.

Comment: found this which seems to be relevant: http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Listening_to_Music#Background

Comment: AFAIK, Itzhak Perlman is a non-religious Jew. So, all the years that he has played his violin both as a soloist as well as with multiple orchestras, Jazz bands, movie and T.V. productions, etc. he has been committing aveirot for the past 60 years?

Answer (score 3):

In [Siman 122](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0121_L2) the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch allows a Jewish Musician to continue playing music for non-Jews until Rosh Chodesh Av.

> יִשְֹרָאֵל שֶׁפַּרְנָסָה שֶׁלוֹ בִּכְלֵי זֶמֶר, מֻתָּר לְנַגֵּן בְּבֵית אֵינוֹ יְהוּדִי בִּכְדֵי פַּרְנָסָתוֹ עַד רֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ. אֲבָל מֵרֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ עַד אַחַר הַתַּעֲנִית, אָסוּר. וְיוֹם שִׁבְעָה עָשָׂר בְּתַמּוּז עַצְמוֹ גַּם כֵּן אָסוּר, וְכֵן עֲשָׂרָה בְּטֵבֵת.‏

He doesn't mention that there's an issue playing for non-Jews.

However, the Shulchan Aruch in [סימן תקס - לעשות זכר לחרבן](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_32.html#HtmpReportNum0011_L2) forbids all types of singing and music - except for praising Hashem.

The Rema is more lenient, allowing it at weddings and (seemingly) occasionally, but not as a daily routine.

It would seem that both opinions wouldn't approve of playing for non-Jews on a permanent basis.

> **ג:** וְכֵן גָּזְרוּ שֶׁלֹּא לְנַגֵּן בִּכְלֵי שִׁיר וְכָל מִינֵי זֶמֶר וְכָל מַשְׁמִיעֵי קוֹל שֶׁל שִׁיר לְשַׂמֵּחַ בָּהֶם; <sub>**הגה:** וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דַּוְקָא מִי   שֶׁרָגִיל בָּהֶם, כְּגוֹן הַמְּלָכִים שֶׁעוֹמְדִים וְשׁוֹכְבִים בִּכְלֵי שִׁיר אוֹ בְּבֵית הַמִּשְׁתֶּה (טוּר),</sub> וְאָסוּר לְשָׁמְעָם מִפְּנֵי הַחֻרְבָּן; וַאֲפִלּוּ שִׁיר בַּפֶּה עַל הַיַּיִן, אֲסוּרָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: בַּשִּׁיר לֹא יִשְׁתּוּ יָיִן (יְשַׁעְיָה כד, ט) וּכְבָר נָהֲגוּ כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל לוֹמַר דִּבְרֵי  תִּשְׁבָּחוֹת אוֹ שִׁיר שֶׁל הוֹדָאוֹת וְזִכְרוֹן חַסְדֵי הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא, עַל הַיַּיִן. <sub>**הגה**: וְכֵן לְצֹרֶךְ מִצְוָה, כְּגוֹן, בְּבֵית חָתָן וְכַלָּה, הַכֹּל שָׁרֵי (תּוֹסָפוֹת וּסְמַ''ג וְהַגָּהוֹת מַיְמוֹנִי).</sub>
>   ‏

Answer (score 1):

I heard on a daf yomi shiur

That
, The reason that music is forbidden is that it is not good to rejoice after the Bais hamikdosh was destroyed, the reasons it is permitted is it is used for good things (wedding) or it has torah in the lyrics (so by singing or listening you are leaning)

Comment: hazoriz do you remember which mesechta? this sounds like the Shulcan Aruch i've heard, that music is forbidden all year (not just sefiras haomer), but from what I remember it's a machlokes..

Comment: @Hugh I am looking for it now

Comment: @Hugh The shulchan aruch http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.560.3

Comment: @Hugh See Bais yosef 3 http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2607 , he brings that for a mitzva (wedding) ok, and brings form sota 48a and gitin 7a

Comment: @Hugh The ramo in sif 3 seems to say it is only forbidden for people like kings that are used to music or by parties, but for a wedding ok. http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2922

Comment: @hazoriz Not just kings, but anyone who is used to going to sleep or waking up to music, such as those with musical alarm clocks.

Comment: Isn't there a rather detailed letter in Igrot Moshe that addresses listening to music, in general? I am disturbed that there would be an active prohibition for all musicians. My father-in-law made his *parnassa* not just in the Jewish wedding business but also playing in klezmer and jazz bands. He also played at a few Lubavitch events that were not "Simcha" related. It seems the Rebbe had no problem with what he did for a living. He constantly hired him. So, my father-in-law wasn't allowed to play in a jazz band?

Comment: @DanF It seems that for mitzvahs it is permitted (not only simhas choson vkala) so if by playing the music he was doing a mitzva it should be permitted, (everything we do we need to do lishma, http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.231) (lubavicher Rebbe not only did himself but told others to also ( shulchan aruch orach haim 231.1) ...בְּכָל דְּרָכֶיךָ דָּעֵהוּ אָמְרוּ חֲכָמִים: כָּל מַעֲשֶׂיךָ יִהְיוּ לְשֵׁם שָׁמַיִם, שֶׁאֲפִלּוּ דְּבָרִים שֶׁל רְשׁוּת...)

Comment: @DanF Please give the source of the letter

Comment: @hazoriz Would you know if there isa table of contents or some way to narrow down *Igorot Moshe* by topic / subject? Otherwise, I would have a a tough time finding it unless I get lucky.

Comment: @DanF See first comment on the question, there are a few more hetairem